# No module named 'pyrosetta.rosetta'

Tags: python, module, bioinformatics, rosetta

I'm trying to install pyrosetta (after I downloaded the tar files and request for a license).
I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtual environment in Anaconda-navigator
The installation step that I did are the following:

I compiled the rosetta in the base environment (rosetta_src_2021.16.61629_bundle release)
I download the Pyrosetta PyRosetta4.MinSizeRel.python37.ubuntu.release-299 release
I activated using `conda activate env  my virtual environment` with 3.7.11 python.
From the main PyRosetta directory, I did python setup/setup.py install and it succeded.

```
Installed /home/user/anaconda3/envs/BioCom/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyrosetta-2017-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for pyrosetta==2017
Finished processing dependencies for pyrosetta==2017
```

(I also tried in the Rosetta directory under pyrosetta folder)

But when I start using python inside the env this error appears:

```
>>> from rosetta import *
>>> from pyrosetta import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/BioCom/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyrosetta-2017-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyrosetta/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pyrosetta.rosetta as rosetta
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrosetta.rosetta'
```

I really dont' know what to do next,
thank you!

Comment: This is really something to ask the package publisher since it's closed source. Could be a namespace problem on your side but who knows.

Comment: I also currently face the same issue in our remote environment. After doing the set-rosetta and activating the Conda environment, it seems due to the original rosetta scripts, we can not run the current python version 3.8 as it requires a lower version (3.7). After resolving the issue with the remote server guru, I will come back and inform the status!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. I solved it by exporting the directory to pyrosetta to my bashrc file.

Step1: Enter `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal. This should open up your .bashrc file.

Step2: Add the following line to your bashrc:

```
PATH=$PATH:<address/to/your/pyrosetta/directory>
```

Step3: Save and close the .bashrc file. Use `exec bash` and then you try running your code again.